# Relative/ responsive positions for <text> in svg? Is it possible?

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<div class="wrap">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="200" width="200">
    <text x="0" y="15">Text one</text>
    <text x="100" y="15">Text two</text>
    <text x="200" y="15">Text three</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I got this svg, is it possible to give each text element relative positions? So when `Text one` (which is obviously a placeholder) becomes longer it automatically pushes `Text two` more to the right? I couldn't find anything about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `<tspan>` elements inside `<text>` and `dx` for the space between

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="200" width="200">
    <text x="0" y="15">Text one<tspan dx="10" >Text two</tspan><tspan dx="10">Text three</tspan></text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. But do you think I need the `y=" "` in the tspan? If I leave it out they inherit from the `<text>` but I'm not sure if this causes any problems I don't see now

Comment: Yes you are right. In this case you don't need the y